# Реализация алгоритма Peak Finder на C#

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм, двоичный-поиск

Разбираю на досуге курс [Введение в алгоритмы от MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/)

На первой лекции ожидал услышать о бинарном поиске и элементарных алгоритмах сортировки, но внезапно получил Peak Finder. Отправился гуглить => результат гуглёжки (на русском внятной инфы не нашёл): [Годная статья хорошего человека](https://www.filipekberg.se/2014/02/10/understanding-peak-finding/)

Идея ясна, но не могу понять, что происходит в коде в случае с одномерным массивом {1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 3}

```
if a[n/2] < a[n/2 - 1] then only look at the left 1 ... n/2 - 1
else if a[n/2] < a[n/2 + 1] then only look at the right n/2 +1 ... n
else n/2 is a peak
```

**Алгоритм для тех, кто не хочет переходить по ссылке на статью:**

Необходимо найти пик(любой) в массиве.
Пиковый элемент массива есть n, элемент слева от которого (a) и справа от которого (b) либо равен ему по значению, либо меньше его:

**n - пик, если a ≤ n ≥ b**

[image: пиковые значения массивов]

Берём значение в массиве и сравниваем с соседями. Если пик - отлично, программа завершена. Если нет - ищем дальше. Перемещаемся влево или вправо на одно число и снова сравниваем. отлично, программа завершена. Если нет - ищем дальше. Ну и так далее.

**1 Вопрос:**
Пиков может быть несколько. Каким образом доработать алгоритм так, чтобы после нахождения пика программа продолжала работать, пока не найдёт все пики?

**2 Вопрос:**
После первой итерации сравнения соседних значений программа должна переместиться влево или вправо по массиву. Указать ей явно, в какую сторону она должна двигаться как-то не логично, ведь после нахождения всех пиков слева ей нужно вернуться обратно и гулять направо. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Идея ясна` - похоже, не совсем.

Для быстрого поиска **не перемещаемся** на один элемент, а ищем в той половине, в которой точно должен быть пик (в правой, если правый элемент больше среднего). Это похоже на бинарный поиск и позволяет найти пик за логарифмической время. На каждом шаге интервал поиска сужается примерно вдвое.

Для поиска всех пиков достаточно линейного прохода по массиву, деление пополам здесь вроде ни к чему (например, в массив из всех одинаковых все элементы пики)

Comment: Да, действительно, как я найду всё пики в массиве, если буду что-то отсекать. Только перебор по сути